# How to combine two optimization problems in R with optim(.)?

Tags: r, optimization

Roughly speaking, I seek to solve a maximation problem in R, where the objective function has the following structure: log[f(theta)*g(theta)]. Thus I want to solve

Max log[f(theta)*g(theta)]

The problem comes from the fact that g(theta) is obtained from another (minimization) problem in theta with restrictions. g(theta) is defined as:

g(theta) = argmin {Min h(x,theta)*g}.

Since h(x,theta) depends on theta, the optimal g that minimizes h(x,theta)*g must be a function of theta.

My approach, so far, has been to first define the function constrOptim(.) such that I can tell R that I want to minimize h(x,theta)*g subject to some restrictions, and then I incorporate that optimal g(.) into the second function (in theta). With this, I use the function optim(.) to try to max log[f(theta)*g(theta)].

Here is my code:

First, the function `problem_min`, which is a function of theta, gives the optimal g(theta), which is obtained as a solution to the minimization problem with constraints (`sol_min`).

```
problem_min <- function(theta_est){
  
  reg_theta_int <- reg_matrix%*%theta_est
  
  for(i in 1:(n*T)){
    for (j in 1:length(alpha)){
      L_1[i,j] = exp(alpha[j]+reg_theta_int[i])/(1+exp(alpha[j]+reg_theta_int[i]))  
    }
  }
  
  y_tilde <- full_data$y - L_1[,1]
  L_1_tilde <- L_1[,-1] - L_1[,1]
  
  eval_funct_g <- function(g){
    return((sum((y_tilde-L_1%*%g)^2))*0.5*(1/n)*(1/T))
  }
  
  sol_min <- constrOptim(theta = g_int, f = eval_funct_g, grad = NULL, ui = R, ci = r, mu = 1e-04,
                           method = "Nelder-Mead",
                           outer.iterations = 100, outer.eps = 1e-05,
                           hessian = FALSE) 
  
  g_theta  = c(1-sum(sol_min$par), sol_min$par)  
  return(g_theta)
  }
```

Once I have the optimal g(theta), which is a vector of numbers, I plug in log[f(theta)*g(theta)] to maximize the whole expression using  `optim(.)` :

```
funct_f_g <- function(theta_est){ 
   full_data$reg_theta_est <- reg_matrix%*%theta_est
   
   for(i in 1:n){
     for (j in 1:length(alpha)){
       for(t in 1:T){
         product[t] = exp(full_data$y[full_data$t==t & full_data$id==i]*(alpha[j]+full_data$reg_theta_est[full_data$t==t & full_data$id==i]))/(1+exp(alpha[j]+full_data$reg_theta_est[full_data$t==t & full_data$id==i]))  
       }
       L_ml[i,j] = prod(product)
     }}
   
   return(sum(log(L_ml%*%problem_min(theta_est))))
 }
 


 sol_ml <- optim(par = theta_int, fn = funct_f_g, method=c("Nelder-Mead"),
                 lower=-Inf, upper=Inf,
                 control=list(fnscale=-1),
                          hessian = FALSE) 
 
 theta_opt <- sol_ml$par
 }
```

`sol_ml` intends to solve Max log[f(theta)*g(theta)] while incorporating the fact that g(theta) should be previously chosen optimally.

A variable_int means that it gives an initial value.

When I run the previous code R tells me that the objective function in  `optim(.)` cannot be evaluated. Nevertheless, when I evaluate `funct_f_g` at some give `theta_est` it runs perfectly. Thus I think that there is something wrong with the `optim(.)` function regarding how I am trying to tell R that the problem has the previous structure.

If you have a different approach to approach my problem, or an explanation about what I am not doing correctly, it will be great!

I know that I am not giving a description of all the matrices and operations that are involved in the previous problem. I skip this for simplicity, hoping that the general structure of the problems can be understood.

Comment: `esp` is a vectorized function. Could you rewrite your functions with no for loops?

Comment: I guess I don't quite understand the problem. What good does knowing the value of `theta` that minimizes `g(theta)` do if you're going to re-estimate `theta` such that it maximizes `log(f(theta)*g(theta))`?   Are you really estimating `theta2` that maximizes `log(f(theta2)*g(theta1))` where ahead of time, you estimate `theta1` that minimizes `g(theta1)`?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, oh I see the problem. Let me rewrite it correctly, sorry!

Comment: @DaveArmstrong. I understand that optim solves problems by iteration. Ultimately, I want  R to understand that it has to evaluate f(theta)*g(theta) at each value, where g(theta) is the argmin of the first minimization problem, and therefore is a function of theta.

Comment: @TUC1685 OK, so you get a value of `theta` that minimizes `g(theta)`, let's call this `G`.  Then you want to maximize `log(f(theta)*G)` (assuming the `theta` in `g(theta)` is fixed at is previously optimized value? But, it sounds like you want to do this for every iteration of the first optimization problem on `g()`?

Comment: @TUC1685 Sorry for being so dense, just trying to wrap my head around the problem conceptually.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong, not quite. R has to understand that in the second problem g(theta) is not a constant, but a function of theta as f is. Even though g is a solution of a minimization problem, it changes if we change theta. I want R to understand this while finding the solution to the maximization problem. g cannot be fixed while solving the maximization.  Do not worry, I don't know how to explain my problem better.